# Is there an Arithmetized Completeness theorem for intuitionistic theories?

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

For classical theories, Henkin's completeness proof can be arithmetized. This leads to the result that for classical theories $T$ and $S$ if $\sigma$ is a formula enumerating $S$ in $T$ then $S \leq T + Con_{\sigma}$. In other words, if a classical theory can prove the consistency of another classical theory it can interpret that theory.

Can a similar thing be done for non-classical theories? I imagine if there is a way to arithmetize a completeness proof for other logics this may be possible. However, Kripke models have a more complicated truth condition so that might also be an issue. Let me know if you have seen anything about this, I have looked around and have not been able to find much information.

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of interpretation in mind? The answer may depend on which one you use.

Comment: Ah, yes sorry. I mean relative interpretation. A recursive function that commutes with logical operators and has a domain. Ideally without parameters but with parameters are fine.

Comment: I don't know if I can fill in all of the details of this, but I feel like there's basically no way it's going to work. Here's an informal argument: Heyting arithmetic together with any true $\Pi^0_1$ sentence should still have a good realizer interpretation. Consider the theory that is $\mathsf{PA}$ together with a unary predicate $U$ together with axioms asserting that $U$ separates some pair of computably inseparable sets.

Comment: $\mathsf{HA}$ proves that this theory is consistent if and only if $\mathsf{PA}$ is, so if there is an arithmetized completeness theorem, $\mathsf{HA} + \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ will be able to interpret this expanded theory. So suppose there is such an interpretation. $\mathsf{HA}$ should be smart enough to be able to define a map from the real natural numbers to an initial segment of the interpreted model, but then $U$ will give you a predicate (satisfying excluded middle) separating two computably inseparable sets.

Comment: Since $\mathsf{HA}+ \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{PA})$ still has a realizer interpretation, the proof of this would give you a program that allows you to computably separate the computably inseparable sets, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Do you think this is because we are trying to interpret a classical theory? I see that this Idea probably would not work for all extensions of $HA$ because $PA$ is an extension. The more specific question I have been trying to figure out is if it is the case that $HA + \neg Con(HA) \leq HA + Con(HA)$. Because $HA \vdash Con(HA) \to Con(HA + \neg Con(HA))$ this would follow from my question but maybe there is still another way to show that.

Comment: After some more thought, I have convinced myself that this is also false

Comment: It's partially because we're trying to interpret a classical theory, but it doesn't need to be a fully classical theory. It just needs to have enough instances of excluded middle to be able to decide non-computable information.

Comment: With regards to your more specific question, somehow I think Tennenbaum's theorem is going to give you trouble, since $\mathsf{HA}+\mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{HA})$ interpreting $\mathsf{HA}+\neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{HA})$ ought to be giving you a computable copy of the atomic diagram of a non-standard model of arithmetic, which you can't have.

Comment: Although this might depend on what you mean by $\neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathsf{HA})$ precisely. Do you mean that that there is a proof of $0=1$ from $\mathsf{HA}$ or do you mean that it's not true that all proofs fails to be proofs of $0=1$ from $\mathsf{HA}$?

Comment: It doesn't matter anymore, but I believe $HA$ has double negation elimination on $\Sigma_1$ predicates, so it should not matter.